# C#: Switch return value type depending on a value

Tags: c#, generics

I need an advice, please. The situation is as follows:

I have a library for operationing with some of hardware. One of the parameters of the machine is Quant (how many products should be in a package). It can be of three types:

```
*quant type | value type*
 Weight     | double
 Pieces     | Integer
 Without    | null
```

I can create a struct for storing Quant values, for example:

```
public struct Quant
{
    public QuantTypes QuantType { get; set; }
    public double QuantWeightValue { get; set; }
    public int QuantPieceValue { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But during work process i need to check many times the state and value of quant. And it turns difficult, because I need to get value depending on quantType

```
if(QuantType == QuantTypes.Piece)
{
     if(QuantWeightValue > 5)
          QuantWeightValue += 2.5;
}
else
{     
     if(QuantPieceValue > 5)
          QuantPieceValue  += 2;
}
SetNewQuantToMachine();
```

I don`t like it. I can make only one field for quant value of double type. But such way opens a possibility to set quant of piece type with non-integer value. In this case I see two solutions:

1. Manually round the value during set;
2. Throw an exception if someone tried to set non-integer piece quant;

Maybe someone wiil give me an advice what is best practice to write such a code. Maybe GenericTypes are suitable in this situation?

Comment: If you need totally different behaviors based on type, maybe you want to make Quant a class and subclass it. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make separate classes for each subtype of Quant. Provide a method that takes `IQuant` interface, and dispatches to a type-specific override using `dynamic`:

```
interface IQuant {
    QuantTypes QuantType { get; }
}
class QuantWeight {
    public QuantTypes QuantType {
        get { return QuantTypes.Weight; }
    }
    public double QuantWeightValue { get; }
}
class QuantCount {
    public QuantTypes QuantType {
        get { return QuantTypes.Pieces; }
    }
    public int PiecesValue { get; }
}
```

Your public method will look like this:

```
public void ProcessQuant(IQuant quant) {
    ProcessQuantImpl((dynamic)quant);
}
private void ProcessQuantImpl(QuantWeight weight) {
    ... // Do the real work here
}
private void ProcessQuantImpl(QuantCount pieces) {
    ... // Do the real work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i get it wrong. But i can suggest to change "Quant" to class setup base version with all calculation, then create number of inherited classes with a different variables and then just use something like "quant.GetValue()". Does it make sense?

Comment: This is basically what @DangerZone was mention